# Adding padding to display:table-cell

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I'm trying to horizontally align `<li>` elements while having them vertically aligned within a `100px` by `100px` box. But I'd also like a bit of `padding` between each element.

Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/as3js51m/1/)

```css
.toolbar ul {
  display: table-row;
}
.toolbar ul li {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100px;
  list-style-type: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: red;
  margin: auto;
}
.toolbar ul li a {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="toolbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Kids<br />
                Grades 0-6
             </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Teens<br />Grades 7-12</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Basically, I'm looking for the same thing but with some `padding` between each element.

Comment: If you want to add padding left or right  .toolbar ul li a {padding:0 5px;}

Comment: I do so, but it doesn't actually create padding between the elements, just adds to the width: https://jsfiddle.net/as3js51m/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm not sure if I'm being clear. I'm looking to turn them into two
>   distinct blocks

so you can use `border-spacing`, because `margin` won't work in `table-cell`

```css
.toolbar ul {
  display: table;
  border-spacing: 5px;
  border: black 1px solid;
  padding:0
}
.toolbar ul li {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100px;
  list-style-type: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.toolbar ul li a {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="toolbar">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Kids<br />
                Grades 0-6
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Teens<br />Grades 7-12</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I do, but it doesn't add padding between elements, just increases box height/width: https://jsfiddle.net/as3js51m/1/

Comment: did you run my snippet at least?, in this fiddle you don't have any `padding` at all

Comment: I did, but there is no padding between the elements. I'm not sure if I'm being clear. I'm looking to turn them into two distinct blocks.

Comment: so you want  `margin`, not `padding`

Comment: Sorry. I'm a bit slow this morning. Yes. But whatever margins I'm adding aren't showing either (I've been trying both).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

add padding into your css

```
.toolbar ul li {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100px;
    list-style-type: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: auto 10px;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/9f4yL9d3/)

Comment: did you read OP comment at least? `I'm looking to turn them into two distinct blocks`

Comment: Yeah, I had a sever case of the dumbs this morning. Thank you all for giving me a hand.